# Use of parent and find to select an item in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this js to update a span value with a new value coming from some math.

```
$('.ammesso').blur(function(){
    ammesso = $(this).val();
    perc_worst ='<?php echo $az_info['perc_worst']; ?>';
    if(isNaN(ammesso)){
        console.log(ammesso);
    }else{
        flusso = ammesso*perc_worst/100;
        var jsonObject = $.parseJSON(prevs); 
        console.log(prevs);
        $.each(jsonObject, function (i, obj) {
            console.log(obj.id);
            var id_item = obj.id;
            //it gets the right value of 393
            console.log('testo: '+$(this).parent('fieldset').find('.cl'+id_item).text());
        });
        console.log('flusso calcolato: '+flusso);
    }
});
```

The html is the following:

```
<fieldset>
    <label>Ammesso: </label><input type="text" name="ammesso[0]" value="" class="ammesso numerico">
    <label>Incassi previsti: </label>
        <ul id="lista">
            <li class="soff_grp">Value - <span class="cl393">CASH</span></li>
        </ul>
</fieldset>
```

`console.log('testo: '+$(this).parent('fieldset').find('.cl'+id_item).text());` should return what is now inside the span but I miss what is wrong and why I cannot select the span. 
My assumptions are:

- with .parent('fieldset') I come back to the first DOM element input
  and span have in common
- with .find('.cl'+id_item) I get the first    element with that class
  (that is present in the rendered HTML)

What is wrong in how I use this two selectors? As per what I understand of what I have read in the jQuery documentation it seems to me the right way to select it!

Comment: Rather than echoing your data directly into a variable in the JS script, you should really be saving that to a data attribute and query that for your value with JS. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Comment: You are right. Thanks for the hint. I use this method for so called general parameters but I can use a hidden element to store them all.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong right now, maybe you can add some debug statements: `console.log(id_item, '.cl'+id_item, this); console.log($(this).parent('fieldset'), $(this).parent('fieldset').length); console.log($(this).parent('fieldset').find('.cl'+id_item), $(this).parent('fieldset').find('.cl'+id_item).length);`. Also, why this is no `var` statement for `ammesso`, `perc_worst` and `flusso` variables ?

Comment: @pomeh see the below answer for the solution! It's not that obvious at first. I change the context while iterating in the json.

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong, but doesn't `$(this)`  refers to the current item in the `$.each` iteration of  `jsonObject` .

Comment: @DavidDomain yes. This is what is pointed out in the below answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the context of input element is lost in each function. `this` refers to element in `jsonObject` on which you are iterating. You need to store the element context outside each loop and then use it in each function:

```
 var fieldset = $(this).parent('fieldset');
 $.each(jsonObject, function (i, obj) {
        console.log(obj.id);
        var id_item = obj.id;
        //it gets the right value of 393
        console.log('testo: ' + fieldset.find('.cl'+id_item).text());
 });
```

Comment: Nice catch ! :) Maybe even better with `var fieldset = $(this).parent('fieldset');` and `fieldset.find('.cl'+id_item)` directly ;)

Comment: @pomeh: good suggestion. please go ahead and edit the answer :)